# make a playlist of audio with ngCordova media / onic / firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, audio, ionic-framework, firebase

H everybody , i am a beginner on hybrid aps and i use ionic framework . I want to stream audio from my firebase console to my application . i have always uploaded the database including the URL for every audio but in all tutorial i have seen , they just play one song but me i want to play a whole playlist from the firebase storage . this is the part of my code where i display the playlist

```
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="song in songs " ng-click=(play("song.url")) >
      {{song.songName}}
      {{song.artistName}}
      </li>
   </ul>
```

Please help me , I am stuck at this point for days now ...

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a bit that goes into getting media playing on devices, and the easiest way I have found is to use the Cordova Media Plugin (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media/). You have to keep in mind that you probably want to be able to stop playing the song once it has started, have pause and resume functionality, and keep everything as clean as possible.

I wrote an application called Serenity (Google Play and App Store soon) that is a meditative app with a music playlist of sorts, and it also has functions for the pause/play/stop functionality. It's on a public Github Repo (https://github.com/tjuranek/MeditationApplication/tree/master/MeditationApplication).

I also use a ng-repeat to create the playlist on my index.html page, and then all of the code to control the media is in app.js. This doesn't stream music unfortunately, but it should be a good start!